# Override Struts 2 Messages

Tags: java, file-upload, error-handling, struts2

In my struts.xml I have:

```
<action name="file_save" method="fileSave" class="FileActionBean">
                <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                    <param name="maximumSize">
                        5242880
                    </param>
                    <param name="allowedTypes">
                        text/html
                    </param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
                <result name="success" type="redirect">file</result>
                <result name="error">error</result>
</action>
```

When I upload a file that's bigger than 5MB then no error is thrown. Then at the top of my struts.xml I have:

```
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="20971520" />
```

Now when I upload a file that's bigger than 20MB then an error message is shown. Is this normal behaviour?

If so, how can I configure struts to show error messages for interceptors too?

**EDIT 1:**

I'm using struts 2 version 2.1.8.1

Comment: seems the global conf overrides the others.

Comment: Yes that is correct. By following the previous link I've also resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in this post:

[How do you override Struts 2 Messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154393/how-do-you-override-struts-2-messages)

I found that by following [this example](http://struts2-by-ash.blogspot.com/2012/06/override-struts-2-messages.html) I resolved both this issue and the one above.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you take your file size validation code to your action class then in validation method check for file size and if it violates then `addActionError("your msg")` and display it in your jsp.

```
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="-1"/>
```

try this with your struts constant and set interceptor file size to your desired size.

Comment: I tried that but it still only shows the message when the file size exceeds the constant, not the param.